# Navigation Drawer right gap

Tags: java, android, navigation, border, drawer

in the dev guidelines they say the gap to the right displayborder shall be 56dp if the nav drawer is opened. How can I do that? Because in the xml "match_parent - 56dp" doesnt work. :D
[Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-specs)
Thx for help!

Comment: What is "match_parent - 56dp"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think it's 56dp by default for most Drawer widgets like **android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout**
- The equivalent for **"match_parent - 56dp"** would be **layout_width="match_parent"** and **layout_marginRight="56dp"** for your xml view or layout inside your bigger layout.

Comment: Im using linearlayout.

Comment: actually it doesn't matter, you can also use it inside a LinearLayout.

Comment: you can use it inside RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, FrameLayout or even GridLayout and TableLayout.